# Convert PHP files of CGI web application to CGI C++ files

Tags: php, c++, web-services, cgi, lighttpd

I am running an embedded webserver `lighttpd` which processes `CGI` requests to `php` module. I need to convert `php` files to `C++` as processing becomes slow in php when number of clients are increased.

Is there any tool or method by which I can convert all `php` files to their equivalent `C++` code?

Comment: maybe try HipHop PHP - it is what Facebook uses to perform the conversion you mentioned

Comment: Are you actually sure that this will be of any great benefit?

Comment: @verbumSapienti: I need C++ files to run on Linux, not sure whether HipHop generates generic C++ files or files suited for it's VM.